# Dropbox oAuth1 and oAuth2 eol

Tags: dropbox-api

Dropbox currently supports oAuth1 and oAuth2.
I was looking for deadlines for oAuth1, but found none.
Are there any plans to discontinue oAuth1 on behalf of oAuth2? If so, what is the deadline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll keep supporting OAuth 1 as long as we support v1 of the API. (And v1 is the current version.)

Comment: But do note we like oauth2 better! See today's dev blog at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/81/upgrading-a-dropbox-oauth-1-token-to-oauth-2